# Is it possible to add preamble commands when embedding LaTeX/MathJax on google sites?

Tags: html, embed, mathjax, google-sites

I'm recently working on building a math-heavy Google site webpage. So, I often need to embed latex into my page with the `embed` option available by Google. I usually use an HTML code similar to the following example provided [in this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159495/313471):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title></title><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.10/require.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load mathjax -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML-full,Safe"> </script>
    <!-- MathJax configuration -->
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    init_mathjax = function() {
        if (window.MathJax) {
        // MathJax loaded
            MathJax.Hub.Config({
                TeX: {
                    equationNumbers: {
                    autoNumber: "AMS",
                    useLabelIds: true
                    }
                },
                tex2jax: {
                    inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
                    displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
                    processEscapes: true,
                    processEnvironments: true
                },
                displayAlign: 'center',
                CommonHTML: {
                    linebreaks: { 
                    automatic: true 
                    }
                },
                "HTML-CSS": {
                    linebreaks: { 
                    automatic: true 
                    }
                }
            });
        
            MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
        }
    }
    init_mathjax();
    </script>
    <!-- End of mathjax configuration --></head>

<p>$x^2 +y^2+z^2=1$</p>
</html>
```

My only problem with this (wonderful) example is that for my purposes, I've to repeatedly use codes like `$\mathbb{R}$`,`$\mathcal{R}$`, etc. Here are my questions:

- Can one define new commands using the TeX's `\newcommand{}{}` command to define things like, say, `\newcommand{\mb}{\mathbb}` in the above template?
- Secondly, what about the popular AMS-theorem-like environments, e.g., `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}` ?

The main problem with these is that these commands would usually be executed in the "preamble" of a TeX file. I can't figure out how to add something to the preamble in the above (or a similar) template. Can this be done? TIA.